# The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Now I have updated all the dependencies to the latest version then I have faced this issues.

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being
>   requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but
>   resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies
>   tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```

and

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.1"
```

Please help me to resolve this issue... 
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Which Android Studio version and which gradle version are you using?

Comment: 3.2 now am using @Barns

Comment: Have you tried `play-services-maps:15.0.1` and `play-services-location:15.0.1` with `firebase-messaging:17.3.2`? This is what works for me, now.

Comment: Yes, Also same issues occurred

Comment: I am also using  `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'` and `firebase-core:16.0.3`

Comment: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'`, `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0"` and `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"` working to me

Comment: Post your complete gradle file, module gradle and project gradle

Answer (score 3):

This conflict happens because of using older libraries, solution is use latest libraries for all possible.
In my case i was using firebase version 16.0.0 , current latest is 16.0.4 (07-02-2019)

I was using this

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

rather than this

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Android (Project - level build.gradle)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Android (App - level build.gradle)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.chatflutterapp.fullterchat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, in my case, following these steps made it run:

> 1) comment all firebase dependencies
>
> 2) comment all firebase usages from classes
>
> 3) clean and rebuild project
>
> 4) uncomment all commented lines